# An unexpected method call was made. Ensure that the XML is well formed. The stack trace of the method call was : Void WriteFullEndElement()

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, biztalk, biztalk-2013

Using BizTalk I am trying to insert/update the table in the SQL Server database using the stored procedure. I have created a stored procedure and the Table Type like below

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.dept_TT AS TABLE
(
dept_name varchar(64),
jax_dept_id char(32)
)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspInsertorUpdateDept]
@dept_TT dept_TT READONLY
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE dep
 SET dep.dept_name                  = dtt.dept_name,
     dep.jax_dept_id                = dtt.jax_dept_id

FROM [afm].[jax_dept] dep
INNER JOIN @dept_TT dtt ON dep.jax_dept_id = dtt.jax_dept_id

INSERT INTO [afm].[jax_dept](dept_name, jax_dept_id )
SELECT dtt.dept_name, dtt.jax_dept_id
FROM @dept_TT dtt
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM [afm].[jax_dept]
                WHERE jax_dept_id = dtt.jax_dept_id)
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END;
```

When I execute the stored produre in the SQL Server management studio it insert/updates the records as expected. I am consuming this storedprocedure in the biztalk application and tried to run the application it throws error like

> The adapter failed to transmit message going to send port "WcfSendPort_SqlAdapterBinding_Procedures_dbo_Custom_Dep" with URL "mssql://". It will be retransmitted after the retry interval specified for this Send Port. Details:"Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.XmlReaderParsingException: An unexpected method call was made. Ensure that the XML is well formed. The stack trace of the method call was : Void WriteFullEndElement().

I enabled the tracking and tried seeing the XML that is sent to the send port and it looks good like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ns0:uspInsertorUpdateDept xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Procedures/dbo" xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Types/TableTypes/dbo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ns0:dept_TT>
        <ns3:dept_TT>
            <ns3:dept_name>lab1</ns3:dept_name>
            <ns3:jax_dept_id>RRI</ns3:jax_dept_id>
        </ns3:dept_TT>
        <ns3:dept_TT>
            <ns3:dept_name>lab2</ns3:dept_name>
            <ns3:jax_dept_id>RAFAC</ns3:jax_dept_id>
        </ns3:dept_TT>
    </ns0:dept_TT>
</ns0:uspInsertorUpdateDept>
```

Xml generated for the stored procedure in the VS

```
<ns0:uspInsertorUpdateDept xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Procedures/dbo">
    <ns0:dept_TT>
        <ns1:dept_TT xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Types/TableTypes/dbo">
            <ns1:dept_name>dept_namedept_namedept_namedept_namedept_namedept_namedept_named</ns1:dept_name>
            <ns1:jax_dept_id>jax_dept_idjax_dept_idjax_dept_i</ns1:jax_dept_id>
        </ns1:dept_TT>
        <ns1:dept_TT xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Types/TableTypes/dbo">\
            <ns1:dept_name>dept_namedept_namedept_namedept_namedept_namedept_namedept_named</ns1:dept_name>
            <ns1:jax_dept_id>jax_dept_idjax_dept_idjax_dept_i</ns1:jax_dept_id>
        </ns1:dept_TT>
        <ns1:dept_TT xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Types/TableTypes/dbo">
            <ns1:dept_name>dept_namedept_namedept_namedept_namedept_namedept_namedept_named</ns1:dept_name>
            <ns1:jax_dept_id>jax_dept_idjax_dept_idjax_dept_i</ns1:jax_dept_id>
        </ns1:dept_TT>
    </ns0:dept_TT>
</ns0:uspInsertorUpdateDept>
```

[image]
[image]

Not sure what am I missing here. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you try validating your XML-message against the schema  in Visual Studio? Can you put the schema for your stored procedure here as well?

Comment: @StevenVanEycken I updated my question.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your input message neither. Is it a one way port or are you returning a result from SQL as well? Is the Action set on your WCF-SQL Adapter configuration?

Comment: Is it a two way send port?  If so, what's the output schema looking like?  It seems like the error is related to the response from SQL rather than the input.

Comment: @DanField It is the two way send port. I have attached the screen shot of the schema and the tracked messages

Comment: @DanField can you please help me with this. Not sure whatever I do I still get the same error `Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.XmlReaderParsingException: An unexpected method call was made. Ensure that the XML is well formed. The stack trace of the method call was : Void WriteFullEndElement().`

Comment: Going out of the box here, but user defined table types are only supported from SQL Server 2008. Are you sure you are using a compatible version?